# Navigation Bar Appearance Settings don't apply constantly

Tags: uinavigationbar, appearance

I tried to customise my UINavigationBarController:

```
// Customize NavBar Appearance
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                       NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Light" size:35.0]}];

// Set NavBar Bottom Border to White by adding a view with height 1
UINavigationController *navBarController = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
CGFloat navBarWidth = navBarController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;

UIView *navBottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kNavBarHeight- 1, navBarWidth, 1)];
[navBottomBorder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:255.0f alpha:0.25f]];
[navBottomBorder setOpaque:YES];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] addSubview:navBottomBorder];
```

The problem I encounter is, that this added subview randomly disappears when clicking through my tab bar items. Sometimes it is visible perfectly, sometimes only the appearance settings for text and font color are presented. By the way: These are always correct. Only my subview is not showing up anymore after the first boot and switching the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

When I use "insertSubview" instead of "addSubview" it seems to work. So I could imagine, that the navbar is being drawn over my added subview?